# How to "clean" old paper documents?

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, image-manipulation

Interpreting old manuscript documents is a challenging task, not only because the way characters were written may differ from the actual modern way, but also because the paper and/or the ink may have deterioted over time (by aging or by accident).
On the example below (from France, 17th century), we can imagine that the stain in the center is caused by some spilled water.
[Example of old manuscript](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pYzF.jpg)

Do you know CV techniques or routine of CV techniques that could be systematically applied to clean such documents ? In the example, it would mean removing the stain and improving the contrast of the faded characters.

EDIT: By applying the method proposed by MarkSetchell (multiplying the image by itself with Imagemagick), this is what I get : [image x image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RiUAX.jpg)

Comment: A simple way is to use an edge detector (like sobel filter) and a thresholding on that.

Comment: A surprisingly effective technique is to multiply the image by itself.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I'm not sure to understand correctly the method you propose. Do you suppose the pixels are floats between 0 and 1 ? In this case, the whole image will get darker, no ?

Comment: You can try it with **ImageMagick** yourself - it is in most Linux distros and available for macOS and Windows. In Terminal, run `magick document.jpg +clone -evaluate-sequence multiply result.jpg`

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thx for your precision. You can see the result in the edited post. It makes both the letters and the stain darker. What would be great is to make the letters darker and the stain lighter.